# ssh connection to remote server failed

Tags: networking, server, ssh

When I tried to connect a remote server (say 'server A') through ssh, it continuously failed with no response and finally showed connection timeout.

The network connection situation is following.

I have several different servers with same first two digits in the ip address e.g. A.B.x.x (Here, A, B are same) in my local computer and servers.

The weird thing is that I can connect other servers including my local computer through ssh from 'server A', however, the opposite way is definitely impossible right now: SSH connection from any server to 'server A'.

I also checked port 22 is opened on 'server A', with `netstat -tuplen`.

What can I try to solve it or please comment anything we can see to realize what's the exact situation is.

Comment: Can you ping 'Server A' from the other computers (is there a route to it)?

Comment: You might want to check to make sure you have the proper netmask on your network as well. Also, are there multiple switches and such in place? Sometimes extra links of switch to switch can monkey with routing.

Comment: Also, can you try doing a verbose connection and see where it stalls?

Comment: @steeldriver when I ping 'Server A', the packets are transmitted and also they are received. It seems that the only problem is that the connection through 'ssh id@ServerA' doesn't work

Comment: I found that 'ssh id@ServerA' from 'Server A' itself succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your keys and reconnecting, they're stored in:

~/.ssh/authorized_keys

It worked for me when I had something similar sounding...

Comment: I cannot find ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: It's hidden directory (i.e. uses a . prefix), so you need to use ls -a to see it. If  it's still not there something probably went wrong with ssh.